# How to display images from sqlite into a flex datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, image, sqlite, actionscript, datagrid

I have a number of thumbnail images (8K ish in length), stored in a sqlite database, encoded as base64 strings.

I would like to retrieve these images and present them into a datagrid (along with some other information from the DB)

The retrieval of information from the database works, but I cannot quite "see" how to connect the decoded result from the database to the datagrid, to display the images.

Below is some code, where I show (to simplify things) a simply DGrid and want to use the dataprovider to point to the select from the DB

Any details to show how I need to change this code would be greatly appreciated:-)

```
  <mx:DataGrid id="dg2" dataProvider="{dp2}">
    <mx:columns>
      <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Image"  dataField="image"  width="150"/>
    </mx:columns>
  </mx:DataGrid>
```

The code to generate the dp2 information is as follows.
The result2 array is populated as expected and ldr appears to be populated, but imageBMap and (therefore) dp2 are null.

```
    sql2.text = "SELECT image FROM  bookMarks;";
    sql2.execute();

    var result2:SQLResult = sql2.getResult();        
    var data2:Array = result2.data;

    var base64Dec:Base64Decoder;
    var byteArr:ByteArray;
    var bmap:Bitmap;
    var ldr:Loader = new Loader(); 
    base64Dec = new Base64Decoder();


    if(result2.data != null)
    {
      var numRows:int = result2.data.length;

      for(var i:int = 0; i < numRows; i++)
      {     
        for(var columnName:String in result2.data[i])
        {
          if(columnName == "image") // Normally there will be more than 1 column in the select, hence this check
          {
            base64Dec.decode(result2.data[i][columnName]);
            byteArr = base64Dec.toByteArray();                
            ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);                
            ldr.loadBytes(byteArr);
          } 
        } 
      } 
    } 
    var imageBMap:Bitmap = Bitmap(ldr.content);
    dp2 = ArrayCollection(imageBMap);
  }

  private function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
  {
    var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height, false, 0xFFFFFF);
    bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader);        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in **itemRenderer** to display the image:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Image" width="150">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:Image source="{here you put the dataProvider}">
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks and understood.
However, imageBMap (and therefore dp2) is null and I am not sure how to correct the code.

byteArr seems fine and I believe so is ldr.